# Installed Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu; No Longer Boots

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows about a week ago and I can no longer boot in to Windows.  When I attempt to boot, I get the error, "Invalid EFI File Path."  I tried to change the boot parameters for the entry in GRUB from `/dev/sdc1` to `/dev/sda*` (the asterisk representing 1-3) to see if that's the issue since there's actually no Windows install except for on `/dev/sda`, but that didn't exactly work.

Here is the paste from Boot Repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1169189/

I understand that repairing the Windows Boot loader would disallow me from booting in to Ubuntu, but I need to get in to Windows to do some things, so is that worth a shot?

Comment: Have you created the Boot-Repair paste before changing the boot parameters? if yes, please create another paste, so that we know your current situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your own Windows 7 installation media to install the Windows boot loader, then use "EasyBCD" to create a boot entry for Ubuntu on windows boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is this:

```
menuentry "Windows bootmgfw.efi.bkp, generated by Boot-Repair" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 0648-FFF7
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi.bkp
}

menuentry "Windows memtest.efi, generated by Boot-Repair" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 0648-FFF7
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi
}

menuentry "Boot bootx64.efi.bkp, generated by Boot-Repair" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 0648-FFF7
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.bkp
}
```

Note in particular the filenames on the `chainloader` lines -- `bootmgfw.efi.bkp` and `bootx64.efi.bkp` are *not* valid EFI boot loader files, and they don't seem to exist on your disk. The files `bootmgfw.efi` and `bootx64.efi`, however, *do* exist and *are* valid EFI boot loader filenames. (I can't guarantee the files you've got are valid, of course, but the filenames are.) I recommend you change these filenames in the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file and then type `sudo update-grub` to pass those changes on to the GRUB configuration file. You could also manually check the contents of `/dev/sda1` to be sure that those files exist with the proper filenames; there's a possibility that something has improperly renamed the files and then updated your GRUB configuration to match that. I have no idea how GRUB would respond to such abuse.

Answer (score 0):

First try to update the grub with this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Maybe that fixes the grub. If not try to fix the windows MBR (Master Boot Record) with a windows Media. This action will corrupt your grub, but no need to worry. You can fix the grub any-time with just a live media of Ubuntu

Comment: This won't help. This is an EFI install, so the MBR is not used.